# Problem building following upgrade to Android 2.3

Tags: android

I picked up the new 2.3 version of the SDK platform and tools, and when I build, I get eight instances of the error below.  Then errors about missing resources.  Presumably my resources have failed to build.

```
W/ResourceType( 8168): Bad XML block: header size 146 or total size 3145924 is larger than data size 0
```

Googling indicates that perhaps a Clean would fix, but it does not.

Googling also indicates that this error would be caused by a poorly formatted XML document, but I have not changed any resources since the upgrade (or for that matter any code), and the code was building and working fine pre-upgrade.

Any idea what's up, or suggestions to troubleshoot?

Comment: This looks like an error when you RUN, not when you BUILD, right? Is there anything else in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you resolved this yet?

Is there any chance that in your strings.xml file you have values with substitution? By this I mean something like:

```
 <string name="page_number">%d results, showing page %d of %d</string>
```

I found out that the `aapt` now enforces having argument indices for strings with multiple formatters.  Update all strings like this to use indices like this:

```
 <string name="page_number">%1$d results, showing page %2$d of %3$d</string>
```

Do a Project > Clean (or Build the project) and the error should go away.  That's what I did and the error was resolved.

Comment: You rock, that was it.  Where did you find that info on aapt?  If it was in the notes I missed it.

Comment: Hehe, thanks! I seemed to miss it to, I just scoured the Android Developers Google group, and found Romain Guy mentioning this. :) Glad to help! :)

Comment: I think you can also use <string name="something" formatted="false">...</string>

Comment: @anselm: Yes you can do that, but I think they recommend using indices for localization. See this for reference: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/017d92dd987a8682/a884db94eaebfe7b?lnk=raot#a884db94eaebfe7b

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be related.  The adb location has been moved.  Per the documentation -

"If you are upgrading to SDK Tools r8 from an earlier version, note that the the default installed location for the adb tool has changed from /tools/adb to /platform-tools/adb. This means that you should add the new location to your PATH and modify any custom build scripts to reference the new location. Copying the adb executable from the new location to the old is not recommended, since subsequent updates to the SDK Tools will delete the file."

Comment: I encounter the same error, and I have already updated my PATH variable but the error is still there. Other suggestions perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: Please could you post a link to the "If you are upgrading to SDK Tools r8 from an earlier version...." document. I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @NickT: Here's the link http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html . The statement is under "Upgrading from SDK Tools r7".

Comment: Thank you Zarah, I should have posted the link with the excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

You must get the new SDK R8 in if you are going to update things.
update ADT and SDK Manager and things will be fine.